# trying to subsitiute text of variable size

Tags: rust

I apologize for the poor title but its hard to summarize.

I have a function that I am making a PR on. I cannot change any of the scaffolding around it as that would ripple throughout the crate. I need it to operate on the same data and return the same thing.

It takes an array of Strings and returns a collection of &str. (It is readying text for display in a tui widget.). I want to replace the text by the same number of '*' characters (ie make it a password entry text box).

Here is what I started with

```
fn text(&self, top_row: usize, height: usize) -> Text<'a> {
    let lines_len = self.0.lines().len();
    let lnum_len = num_digits(lines_len);
    let bottom_row = cmp::min(top_row + height, lines_len);
    let mut lines = Vec::with_capacity(bottom_row - top_row);
    for (i, line) in self.0.lines()[top_row..bottom_row].iter().enumerate() {
        lines.push(self.0.line_spans(line.as_str(), top_row + i, lnum_len));
    }
    Text::from(lines)
}
```

`lines()` returns an array of `&String`. After some house keeping each line is processed and  inserted as a &str into the `lines` local variable. That is then processed into a Tui::Text
object

This is what I could make work

```
fn text(&self, top_row: usize, height: usize) -> Text<'a> {
    let lines_len = self.0.lines().len();
    let lnum_len = num_digits(lines_len);
    let bottom_row = cmp::min(top_row + height, lines_len);
    let mut lines = Vec::with_capacity(bottom_row - top_row);
    const STARS: &str = "******************************\
                         ******************************\
                         ******************************\
                         ******************************";
    const STARSLEN: usize = STARS.len();
    for (i, line) in self.0.lines()[top_row..bottom_row].iter().enumerate() {
        let mut thisline = line.as_str();
        if self.0.password_mode {
            let count = thisline.chars().count();
            thisline = &STARS[0..cmp::min(count, STARSLEN)];
        }
        lines.push(self.0.line_spans(thisline, top_row + i, lnum_len));
    }
    Text::from(lines)
}
```

as you can see if a flag is set I create a &str pointing at part of a static string literal of stars.

The problem is that If the text gets bigger than my arbitrary size "***" literal then I chop characters off. (Probably wont but thats not the point). Note the `min` call in the slice creation

I tried to make an Rc of **'s of the correct size for each line and get an &str from that but could not make it work.

Note that I cannot change the original Strings array since thats the text the user entered and I still need it

Comment: Hint: when there is a case that data conditionally can be borrowed or owned simultaneously, you need to consider the `Cow` enum as the type. Cow or Clone-on-write, allows you to return either a borrowed `&str` or an owned `String`.

Comment: @Raeisi - rather than a hint could you supply a working implemention

Answer (score 1):

The challenge here is making a string that lives at least as long as `'a`. Normally you would alter the surrounding code so that you have somewhere to stash this string that lives at least as long as `'a`, but you've indicated that you cannot do this.

This is where the [leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.leak) "escape hatch" comes in.  Leaking a string gives you a `&'static str` which (usually) cannot safely be freed later, so it's not something you want to do all over the place, or you will slowly exhaust available memory.  However, if you can do so in a way that causes a practical limit on the number of such leaked allocations, this can be a very convenient way to handle these kind of situations.  (As always, the operating system will free all memory allocated by the process when it terminates, including leaked strings.)

Here, I start with an 8-character string.  If a string of length 8 or under is requested, a slice of the existing string is used to satisfy the request.  If the request is for a larger string, a new string is created and leaked, replacing the existing reference.  This way, a string of any (reasonable) length can be created, while shorter strings will be handled by taking a slice of the larger string.

This should not cause a run-away memory usage issue unless you are repeatedly requesting larger and larger strings.  Assuming a fairly reasonable maximum length and a relatively chaotic distribution of requested lengths, this function will probably allocate a handful of times and then never again.

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn asterisks(num: usize) -> &'static str {
    static STRING: Mutex<&'static str> = Mutex::new(
        // 8 characters to start, but you could use larger.
        "********",
    );

    let mut string = STRING.lock().unwrap();

    if string.len() < num {
        // String is too short.  Double its length at minimum, but ensure it's
        // at least as long as the requested size.  Note we cannot free the
        // prior string because it may still be referenced.
        *string = "*".repeat(std::cmp::max(string.len() * 2, num)).leak();
    }

    &string[0..num]
}
```

This could be improved upon still by eliminating the need for a mutex, using perhaps `RwLock` or an [atomic reference](https://docs.rs/atomic_ref/latest/atomic_ref/).

Comment: Neat. Would I be able later free up those leaked strings?

Comment: @pm100 Not safely. It requires `unsafe` specifically because you've told other things in the program they have `'static` lifetime and so the borrow checker is not going to impose any constraint on their usage. The operating system will free the memory when the program terminates, and assuming there is a bound on how many different values of `num` will be used, the memory usage will eventually plateau.

Comment: @pm100 And in fact there is a way to make this even more efficient. You can round up to the nearest multiple of a chosen number (e.g. 8) and return a slice. So if you use 8 as an example, all strings with length between 1 and 8 inclusive would reference the same 8-character string instead of requiring 8 separate strings. Ideally if you know the maximum length you can just allocate one big string and return slices of it.

Comment: Yup I was thinking that I could start with 100 bytes and then double it if I overflow. If I knew the max size I would simple make my const STARS that size :)

Comment: @pm100 Right. You can do that but you have to leave the 100-byte string around. So there's actually an even easier way to do this... let me update my answer.

Comment: so we just leave the older short erones hanging in mid air?  it feels odd

Comment: Well but you're allocating less than 3x the needed space which is fine honestly, and there's no real workaround there unless you're willing/able to switch the return type to `Cow<'a, str>` or something similar.

Comment: I wouldn't accept code that does such thing instead of doing the obviously correct thing and change the signature, even if it bubbles in the code base.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what 'such a thing'